How can I scan and print the stdout of a process using os.StartProcess
I would like to get the stdout of a process as a stream in Go using os.StartProcess, since exec.Command does not work for my use case in windows (exec.Command freezes after a while in windows, this is an old issue)
this is what i was able to do so far:
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

func main() {

    fileDir := "C:\\Users\\username"
    entrypoint := "main.py"

    r, w, _ := os.Pipe()
    var procAttr os.ProcAttr
    procAttr.Files = []*os.File{os.Stdin, w, os.Stderr}

    outC := make(chan string)
    go func() {
        var buf bytes.Buffer
        io.Copy(&buf, r)
        // I would like to print the bytes copied to the buffer in realtime
        // something like log.Println("buf: ", buf.String())
        // but this would only print in the end of the execution
        // since io.copy is a for loop stream
        outC <- buf.String()
    }()

    p, err := os.StartProcess(
        "C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe",
        []string{
            "C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe",
            "/C",
            filepath.Join(filepath.Dir(fileDir), "venv", "Scripts", "python.exe"),
            filepath.Join(fileDir, entrypoint),
        },
        &procAttr,
    )

    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    } else {
        log.Println("os.StartProcess ok")
        pState, _ := p.Wait()
        log.Println("ExitCode:", pState.ExitCode())
        log.Println("Success:", pState.Success())

        w.Close()
        r.Close()
        out := <-outC
        log.Println("Captured:", out)
    }
}


Just to be clear, printing here is just an example, what I want to do is capture the output as a stream and send it to an external logging service in realtime
I've tried using io pipes, MultiReader and bufio.NewScanner, but with no luck
thanks in advance for your help

Edit - Why exec.command doesn't work (in windows):
There is a bug in the Windows implementation of Go and has been filed on GitHub many times - the oldest I could find is this:
https://github.com/golang/go/issues/42919
The bug is caused by the fact that exec.Command() internally uses os.Stat() which does not read files with reparse points correctly. os.Lstat() can.
Windows Store apps use App Execution Aliases, which are essentially zero-byte files with reparse points. This post has some additional details:
https://www.tiraniddo.dev/2019/09/overview-of-windows-execution-aliases.html
The workaround is to use os.StartProcess(), a lower level API which can be a bit painful to use especially when compared to os/exec exec.Command()

Edit 2 - Thanks to @JimB's help, I was able to achieve what I wanted, I will keep testing and will update here if necessary
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

func main() {

    fileDir := "C:\\Users\\username"
    entrypoint := "main.py"

    r, w, _ := os.Pipe()
    var procAttr os.ProcAttr
    procAttr.Files = []*os.File{os.Stdin, w, os.Stderr}

    grCtx, grCancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    go func(intCtx context.Context) {
        rs := bufio.NewScanner(r)
        for rs.Scan() {
            select {
            case <-intCtx.Done():
                log.Println("scanner finished")
                return
            default:
                log.Println("scanner text: ", rs.Text())
            }
        }
    }(grCtx)

    p, err := os.StartProcess(
        "C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe",
        []string{
            "C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe",
            "/C",
            filepath.Join(filepath.Dir(fileDir), "venv", "Scripts", "python.exe"),
            filepath.Join(fileDir, entrypoint),
        },
        &procAttr,
    )

    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    } else {
        log.Println("os.StartProcess ok")
        pState, _ := p.Wait()
        log.Println("ExitCode:", pState.ExitCode())
        log.Println("Success:", pState.Success())
    }
    w.Close()
    r.Close()
    grCancel()
}


this is what the os/exec package is for. If that’s not working, you will need to figure why and work around it. The correct way to do this will just replicate the code in os/exec

Hello@JimB , thank you for your answer.
I updated the question explaining why os.exec doesnt work

(The specific issue you linked should be fixed in the latest release, but I'm not really familiar enough with Windows to know what related problems might be lurking) What do you mean that it only prints "sometimes"? You have 2 goroutines reading from the same r, so neither can get all the data.

You also started by asking how to copy stdout, but your example is not using stdout at all -- did you want stderr?

Sorry for the confusion, in this case stdout and stderr are the same thing, so it makes no difference which one I capture.
That goroutine below my comment is just a stupid example of what I would like to achieve.
What I mean that it only prints "sometimes" is that it ramdonly prints some of the bytes in the bufoi.scanner, not all of them. I dont expect it to work, its just to make it easier to understand the concept of what im trying to do.
As far as I'm reserching, the only possible solution I see now is to create my own implementation of io.Copy. Why working with windows is always a pain?

This doesn't appear to be related to windows at all, it's not clear what you are trying to do. Does the python process print everything simultaneously to both stdout and stderr (which would be quite unusual)? If you want the pipe data copied to the buffer, have the scanning goroutine put the data there. If you can't do that, use io.TeeReader to wrap the reader and copy the data (which might be what you are trying to do with the second goroutine?)

I fixed my question, JimB, please see if it makes it clear.
Yes, the python process prints everything simultaneously to both stdout and stderr, lol.
This is a windows thing because using os/exec works perfectly in linux,

Now you're not giving the pipe to the process at all, so there can't be any data on it. If you want to print line-buffered output as it's written, go back to the scanner approach you removed. Even if your code read data from the pipe it's obviously not going to print anything until the process is complete when buf.String() sends it back over the channel.

Thank you for your help and patience @JimB, I think I fixed It. This was driving me insane for 3 days, lol. I will make more tests and update here if necessary

FYI ir := io.Reader(r) is pointless, r satisfies the interface, pass it directly to NewScanner. You should also close channels like quitScanner, not send a value (or just use a Context)
